# Unknown exe file (ColorMania) running on my PC

Tags: windows, permissions

I have an unknown exe running on my PC.

I looked in task manager it said the name was `ColorMania (32-Bit)`, Although when I click Properties on this process, it is actually named `GoogleDiagnostics.exe`.

I have tried to delete the file but it errored saying `The specified file does not exist`. Also tried to delete the folder it is in `C:\Users\cfymg\AppData\Roaming\Google`, it errors with "Access is denied".

I have tried everything I can. Giving myself Administrator threw the same error.

Putting my user account in the Administrators group had also thrown the same error.

Please give your advice on what I could do to remove this, other than resetting my PC. I have run a deep scan on my PC and nothing had showed up.

[image: Command Prompt with Administrator permissions]

Comment: `rmdir` only works on empty folders unless you specify additional options.

Comment: `GoogleDiagnostics` does not need to disguise itself as `ColorMania`. Your computer is likely infected.